# How to print the result of a computation involving the value of a counter?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I set the value of the counter `ga` and would like to print the result of a numeric computation involving its final value.

What should I put in place of `\dots`?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\newcounter{ga}
 \setcounter{ga}{0}

 \tikzmath{\u1 = 10; \x1 =10; }
 \draw[double, rounded corners, purple, fill=yellow!3] (0,0) rectangle (\x1+1,\u1+1);
   \foreach \u in {1,...,\u1}{
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\x1}{
      \pgfmathrandominteger{\a}{1}{6}
      \pgfmathrandominteger{\b}{1}{6}
      \ifthenelse{\a<4 \AND \b<4 \AND \NOT \a =\b}
        {\node[blue,draw,circle,font=\scriptsize] at (\x,\u) {sì} \pgfextra{\stepcounter{ga}};}
        {\node[font=\scriptsize] at (\x,\u) {no};}
    }
  }
 % \def\gga{\pgfextra{\stepcounter{ga}}}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\pr}{\u1*\x1}
 %\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\u}{\gga/\pr}
  \node[font=\normalsize] at (\x1/2,-1) {$frequenza=\dfrac{\thega}{\pr}= \dots \mbox {\it in  forma decimale}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: (1) please note that the language is English here, (2) please extend your example to a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is.

Comment: Don't `\newcounter` inside a TikZ picture. Put this once into the preamble. You can't use `\pgfextra` or `\stepcounter` inside a PGFmath expression. `\pgfextra` is only for stuff on a path. Outside of a path you can directly use `\stepcounter`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean “how to *compute* the fraction in decimal form”?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen,tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\newcounter{ga}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
  \tikzmath{\u1 = 10; \x1 =10; }
  \setcounter{ga}{0}
  \draw[double, rounded corners, purple, fill=yellow!3] (0,0) rectangle (\x1+1,\u1+1);
  \foreach \u in {1,...,\u1}{
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\x1}{
      \pgfmathrandominteger{\a}{1}{6}
      \pgfmathrandominteger{\b}{1}{6}
      \ifthenelse{\a<4 \AND \b<4 \AND \NOT \a =\b}
        {\node[blue,draw,circle,font=\scriptsize] at (\x,\u) {sì}; \stepcounter{ga}}
        {\node[font=\scriptsize] at (\x,\u) {no};}
    }
  }
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\pr}{\u1*\x1}
  \node[font=\normalsize] at (\x1/2,-1) {%
    $\mathit{frequenza}=\dfrac{\thega}{\pr}= \fpeval{\thega/\pr}$ \textit{in  forma decimale}%
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want `\fpeval{round(\thega/\pr,2)}` (or whatever maximum number of decimal digits you ask for instead of 2).